# GeoJson FeatureCollection field summary not accessible, indexing not working

Tags: javascript, angular, indexing, geojson, openrouteservice

In my Angular Application, I get some GeoJSON as type `FeatureCollection` from [OpenrouteService](https://openrouteservice.org/dev/#/api-docs/v2/directions/%7Bprofile%7D/get).

Inside my ts file, I just assign the response from OpenrouteService so some variable:

```
import { FeatureCollection } from 'geojson';
...
routeJson: FeatureCollection | undefined;
```

If you look at the response type on their side, the following should work:
`this.routeJson.features[0].properties.summary.distance`
But when I try this, I get the error: “Unresolved variable summary”

Instead, the following works:

```
<aside *ngIf="routeJson">
  <div>
     {{this.routeJson.features[0].properties!['summary'].distance}}
  </div>
</aside>
```

Why is my initial approach not working? Do I get something wrong here?